# My question was deleted but a reason isn't marked

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Here's [a link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233703/respond-to-sharepoint-survey-within-excel) to the question, it's on topic as it relates directly to share point and its functionality.